# Maven 3.0.4 installation to Ubuntu mvn not found

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I tried to install Maven to Ubuntu but something goes wrong.

I downloaded Maven and untarred it to folder `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4.`
Then I added these rows to /etc/environment.

> export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
>
> export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
>
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$M2:$PATH"

But when I try to verify my installation by `mvn --version` I get this message

> 'The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:  * maven  *
> maven2 Try: sudo apt-get install '

**SOLVED.** Sorry that if forget to reply to this. I added export rows to ~/.bashrc and after that it started to work.

Comment: Did you open a *new* terminal window after updating /etc/environment ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, this is how i solved it.

1- Install Maven2 from Synaptic rather than downloading it from the website.

2- `gedit ~/.bashrc` and check if you have M2_HOME and M2 env variables defined if so DELETE them, delete them from PATH too, if there is a reference to them.

3- Reload bash and try`mvn --version` again.

Answer (score 2):

please check if `mvn` in $M2 is executable. if not you need to make it executable by running

```
chmod +x mvn
```

Comment: Yes, mvn in $M2 is executable.

Comment: keep in mind, that after chaning `/etc/environment` it is not enough just to close the gnome terminal and start it again... you have to logout and login again... just double check your $PATH by `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS release, Maven can be installed from the official repository by running following commands:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install maven

Each time you hit `sudo apt update` it will update to the latest version.

Update: After installation is complete, run in the terminal `mvn -v` to see if package was installed.